Returning minimal elements of a set and scientific data analysis
In my field of scientific data processing, each element of data has a set of identifiers associated with it. Those identifiers correspond to periods of actual data-taking, along with finer-grained subperiods within those larger periods, etc.
These identifiers are similar to ordered tuples of numbers (each belonging to $\mathbb{N})$ and they form a poset with the following relations (e.g.):

$[] \succ [1] \succ [1, 2] \succ [1, 2, 5]$.  Used to denote a hierarchy of data taking: period 1, subperiod 2, event 5.
$[1, 2, 5] \prec [1, 2] \prec [1] \prec []$. Just flipping the above around.
$[i, j, k] = [1, 2, 5]$ iff $i = 1$, $j = 2$, and $k = 5$.
$[1, 2, 5] \nsucc [2]$.  Cannot compare identifiers with inconsistent hierarchies (period 1 vs. period 2).

I then want to perform analysis on the data.  Imagine a function $f: A \times B \rightarrow C$ and the data
$a$ associated with $\mbox{ID}_a = \{[1, 2, 5]\}$ and $b$ associated with the identifier $\mbox{ID}_b = \{[1,2]\}$.  To figure out what the function result $c$ should be associated with, I'd like to perform the following operation:
\begin{eqnarray}
\mbox{ID}_c &=& \mbox{minels}\left(\mbox{ID}_a \cup \mbox{ID}_b\right) \\
& = & \mbox{minels}(\{[1, 2, 5], [1,2]\}) \tag{a}\\
& = & \{[1,2,5]\} \tag{b} \\
& = & \mbox{ID}_a
\end{eqnarray}
where $\mbox{minels}(S)$ is an operation that returns the subset of minimal elements of the set $S$.  The progression from eqns. (a) to (b) is because $\mbox{ID}_a \prec \mbox{ID}_B$.  This approach makes sense to me because any data that is part of $[1,2,5]$ is also part of $[1,2]$.
The question: Is it safe to "invent" such a function $\mbox{minels}$ that returns a subset of minimal elements?  I've seen some posts that urge caution when creating functions that return sets.
